# How do you efficiently search across a group of lists in Python?

Tags: python, data-structures

In Python I have a group of lists that track information about some users:

```
user_id = [1,2,3,4,5]
user_name = ['bob', 'alice', 'jerry', 'lisa', 'tom']
user_email = ['bob@email.com', 'alice@email.com', 'jerry@email.com', 'lisa@email.com', 'tom@email.com']
...
```

where the i'th element in each list correspond to each other.

I want to get user info "x" given info "y". In most cases I'd use a dictionary for this for the constant lookup time, but I don't want to build and maintain dozens of dictionaries.

If I maintain a dictionary for every pair of lists shown above I'd have

```
name:email
email:name
name:id
id:name
email:id
id:email
```

which already starts getting unmanageable - and grows very quickly with the number of attributes.

I could have everything map to user_id, and then have only 2n dictionaries, but happy to learn of a more appropriate data structure for this use case.

To illustrate how the code is currently implemented:

```
def get_email_by_user_id(user_id):
   return [email for email, uid in zip(user_email, user_id) if uid == user_id][0]
```

As you can imagine, very slow :P

Comment: Databases have this same issue and they solve it by creating indices for commonly searched fields. This is analogous to your lookup dictionaries. If you want constant time lookups on a field, you need the index; the alternative is to scan the data in linear time. You probably don't need so many though. If you stored the users as single objects, you could have a single `name -> object` lookup rather than `name -> id` `name -> email `etc.

Comment: Just make a list of dictionaries and have a "query" function where you pass the key and the value you want.  Unless you have millions of users, that will work fine.  If not, then use a database (sqlite3?), which will do exactly the same thing.

Comment: Alternatively, store the records in a dictionary with `id` as the key, and have dictionaries that map username to id, or email to id.

Comment: List comprehensions don't return early. Don't use a list comprehension for this (among other things).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I took the only option that gave the the performance I needed

I decided the contents of `user_id` are the canonical identifier.

I then created the following dictionaries:

```
def make_dictionaries(user_id, other_lists=[('user_name', user_name), ('user_email', user_email)]):
   to_id_dictionary = {}
   from_id_dictionary = {}

   for list_name, list_content in other_lists:
      from_id_dictionary[list_name] = {uid:cont for uid,cont in zip(user_id, list_content)}
      to_id_dictionary[list_name] = {cont:uid for uid,cont in zip(user_id, list_content)}

   return to_id_dictionary, from_id_dictionary
```

I can then do:

```
def get_email_by_user_name(user_name):

   uid = to_id_dictionary['user_name'][user_name] # Get UID from name
   return from_id_dictionary[user_email][uid] # Get email from UID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Dict for holding your data
data = dict()
    
# Put all your stuff into data 
for id, name, email in zip( user_id, user_name , user_email):
    data[ id ] = { "id": id , "username" : name , "email" : email }

# Function for lookup up by key and value 
def lookup_info( key_name , lookup_value , data ):
    '''
    Takes a key name, a lookup value and a dictionary of data.

    Returns the dictionary item
    '''
    for k,v in data.items():
        
        if v[ key_name ] == lookup_value:
            return( data[ k ] )
```

Comment: This still would run in O(n)

Comment: True but more organised than previous code. Could otherwise do binary/DFS?

Comment: I don't think binary searches are much help if the data is not sorted.

Comment: Could sort the dicts in "data" array by the lookup key and do it, depends if sort+search would be faster than just a simple loop through - at this point would recommend a database.

Answer (score 0):

Since the data is related they can be organized into a single list of tuples of the related columns.

```py
DATA = [
    (1, 'bob', 'bob@email.com'),
    (2, 'alice', 'alice@email.com'),
    (3, 'jerry', 'jerry@email.com'),
    (4, 'lisa', 'lisa@email.com'),
    (5, 'tom', 'tom@email.com'),
]
```

Then, a general function can be made that considers only the column you are interested in.

```py
def find_user(user_id=None, user_name=None, user_email=None):
    """Find first user matching given criteria.

    A None value means "don't care".

    Returns tuple of (id, name, email) if found, otherwise None.
    """
    # Collect desired criteria into mapping of record index to desired index value.
    criteria_cols = {i: c for (i, c) in enumerate((user_id, user_name, user_email)) if c is not None}
    for rec in DATA:
        if all(rec[idx] == criteria for (idx, criteria) in criteria_cols.items()):
            return rec  # return early if found.
```

This function considers any non-None value, and returns the matching record. If no records match, fall through and return the default None value.

```py
print(find_user(user_id=1))
print(find_user(user_id=2))
print(find_user(user_name="alice"))
print(find_user(user_email="jerry@email.com"))
print(find_user(user_id=3, user_email="jerry@email.com"))
print(find_user(user_id=2, user_email="jerry@email.com"))
print(find_user(user_id=3, user_name="jerry"))
```

Results in

```
(1, 'bob', 'bob@email.com')
(2, 'alice', 'alice@email.com')
(2, 'alice', 'alice@email.com')
(3, 'jerry', 'jerry@email.com')
(3, 'jerry', 'jerry@email.com')
None
(3, 'jerry', 'jerry@email.com')
```